# Division by zero?

Tags: complex-numbers

I came across a problem where we write dividend = divisor $\times$ quotient + remainder, the dividend being divided by the divisor. the exact question was: $f(x) = x^4 + 9x^3 + 35x^2 -x + 4$.

Find value at $x=-5+4i$. here we write $x+5 = 4i$ and by squaring both sides reach an equation $x^2 + 10x + 41 = 0$ and ultimately divide $f(x)$ to get remainder $-160$ and by dividend = divisor $\times$ quotient + remainder, here the divisor being $x^2+10x+41 = 0$ (LHS = RHS = $0$ so we are dividing by $0$). Ans given is $-160$ after putting divisor = $0$ to get value at $x=-5x+4i$.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? As it's written, it's hard to tell what it is.

Comment: Asterisk is used to make italic font, and it ruined the formatting. (I fixed it.) Please use \cdot or \times next time! And in general, use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) whenever you type a formula on this site. It’s pretty easy. You just enclose your formulae into the $ signs, for the most part.

Comment: If I write ${f(x)\over x-a}=q(x)+{{\rm remainder}\over x-a}$ and put in $x=a$, then I'm dividing by zero, and it doesn't work. But if I write the same equation as $f(x)=(x-a)q(x)+{\rm remainder}$, then there isn't any division, and I'm free to substitute $x=a$, to get $f(a)={\rm remainder}$.

Comment: Did you think this was the kind of "division by zero" that people always tell you you can't do? Do you have a question you want to ask?

Answer (score 0):

You can use long division. Not sure the best way to do it here. Here I'm separating parts with $|$ a vertical bar. The first part is the number I'm dividing, second part is factor I'm dividing by, third part is what I want to multiply the factor by, 4th part is the product. First part on the next line is the remainder, otherwise things remain the same. Finally stop when the degree if the remainder is less than the degree of the factor. Then evaluate the remainder at $x=0$.

Then add up the third part from each line to get the quotient.

$x^4+9x^3+35x^2-x+4|x^2+10x+41|x^2|x^4+10x^3+41x^2$

$-x^3-6x^2-x+4|x^2+10x+41|-x|-x^3-10x^2-41x$

$4x^2+45x+4|x^2+10x+41|4|4x^2+40x+164$

$5x-160|x^2+10x+41|...$

So: $x^4+9x^3+35x^2-x+4= (x^2-x+4)(x^2+10x+41)+5x-160$